# getting error while installing tronpy , tronweb , tronapi

Tags: python-3.x, package

i tried install tronpy but it shows legacy-install-failur

full error code below

sing legacy 'setup.py install' for trx-utils, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for bitarray, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: bitarray, cytoolz, attrdict, trx-utils, eth-utils, rlp, eth-keys, eth-abi, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-account, tronweb
Running setup.py install for bitarray ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for bitarray did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [19 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\bitarray
copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\bitarray
copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\bitarray
copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\bitarray
copying bitarray_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\bitarray
running build_ext
building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\bitarray
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /M
D -IC:\Users\Pugazhenthi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Pugazhenthi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include /Tcbitarray/_bitarray.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\bitarray/_bitarray.obj
_bitarray.c
C:\Users\Pugazhenthi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> bitarray

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Until now, tronapi still does not support python 3.10 and above, so you should use python 3.9